# Technology Platform for WebService in non programming company

Tags: web-services, web-applications

The company I am working at is required to develop a web service API. Currently the company does not have in house software or web developers, we are primarily MySQL database developers.

We would like suggestions on languages and frameworks that will allow rapid development of a web service that is basically acting as a proxy to MySQL stored procedures.

We need a framework that is:

1) Quick to learn (so that our staff can pick up the skills to support it)
2) Rapid to develop on
3) Capable of interfacing easily with existing MySQL databases.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

What I first suggest is [Django](http://www.djangoproject.com/) (web framework) with [Piston](http://bitbucket.org/jespern/django-piston/wiki/Home) (RESTful API creation framework). They are programmed in [Python](http://www.python.org), and integrates easily with MySQL.

The classic for doing web development with MySQL is of course [PHP](http://www.php.net). Can't say much about it, but the last time I used it it had a quite "clunky" feel, the language itself felt somewhat weak (that may have changed by now).